# Generative Python transformer hitting Github API

Tags: python, api

I'm working on a GPyT (generative python transformer) project and I have written the below script to download lots of Python files from github.com to train my model. It works fine, but there is a problem I guess because it becomes slower with every file it downloads. It takes more time to download new files and while the size of the Python files is almost the same and small.

At first I wanted to ask my question on Stack Overflow but as the script works and there is no error I thought it would be better to ask it here. To get some advice on my work, because I think it smells spaghetti and there is a performance issue involved.

The part I have doubts about is this 'if` statement:

```
if not os.path.isfile(f'{repos_path}/{file_content.name}')
```

I think it takes longer every time to check if the file exists because the number of files is increasing. It checks against a growing list. I've also checked the memory and CPU usage running this script and there is no difference when I first started the script.

Code:

```
# Part one >>> cloning lots of python related repositories from **GITHUB**
# and put them into repos directory.

import os
import subprocess

import wget
from colorama import Fore
from github import Github
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

""" There are two ways to do so: 1. Clone lots of repositories and then walk through the directories and delete every
single file except python files, 2. Get a specific content file which is the chosen way here """

""" There are many ways to download the files: 1. Using wget, 2. Implementing your own dl.py file in order to
download files using requests library or even making a function named download """

# replace with your desired directory
repos_path = ''


try:
    access_token = open('', 'r').read()
    github = Github(access_token)

    query = 'language:python'
    res = github.search_repositories(query)

    # print(res.totalCount)
    # print(dir(res))

    for repo in res:
        contents = repo.get_contents('')
        while contents:
            file_content = contents.pop(0)
            if file_content.type == 'dir':
                contents.extend(repo.get_contents(file_content.path))
            else:
                # print(f'{Fore.GREEN} + URL: {file_content.download_url}')
                if file_content.path.endswith('.py'):
                    contents_url = file_content.download_url

                    if not os.path.isfile(f'{repos_path}/{file_content.name}'):
                        try:
                            wget.download(
                                contents_url, out=repos_path, bar=None)
                        except HTTPError as http_err:
                            print(
                                f'{Fore.YELLOW} -  "Error occurred": {http_err}')
                            continue
                        except Exception as err:
                            print(f'{Fore.YELLOW} -  "Error occurred": {err}')
                            continue
                        else:
                            print(f'{Fore.GREEN} + {Fore.WHITE} "{file_content.name}" {Fore.GREEN} Downloaded')
                    else:
                        print(f'{Fore.RED} - {Fore.WHITE} "{file_content.name}" {Fore.RED} Exists')


except Exception as e:

    command = 'du -sh repos/'

    paths = []
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(repos_path):
        for f in files:
            fp = os.path.join(path, f)
            paths.append(fp)
    
    print(f'\n{e}')
    print(f'{Fore.WHITE}There are {len(paths)} Python files under "repos" directory')
    subprocess.call(command)
```